# Error While passing File name from array in content.drawSvg

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, 3d, 2d

I am drawing SVG file on Canvas.

For this I am using canvg Javascript SVG parser and renderer on Canvas.

If I use :

context.drawSvg('/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg', 0, 0, 400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue);

then it works fine.

But if I use :

context.drawSvg(images[0], 0, 0, 400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue);

then following error is coming.

**Error : Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'substr' in canvg.js**

images = ["/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg"]

**Original Code:**

```
var dataJSON = data || [];
    var dataJSON2 = data2 || [];
    window.onload = function(){ 
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //tooltipTxt = ["Region 1", "Region 2", "Region 3"];
        var tooltip = null,
                timer;

        console.log(dataJSON);
        var files = ["/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg", "/static/images/green1.png", "/static/images/pink.png"],
        images = [],
        numOfFiles = files.length,
        count = numOfFiles;
        // in files variable no use of svg name. 
        //var x = canvg('myCanvas', '/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg') In this we can load svg with this method also but we used drawSvg method

        /// function to load all images in one go
        function loadImages() {
            /// go through array of file names
            for(var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {
                /// create an image element
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                /// use common loader as we need to count files
                img.onload = imageLoaded;

                //img.onerror = ... handle errors
                img.src = files[i];                 
                /// push image onto array in the same order as file names
                images.push(img);

            }
        }
        loadImages();
        function imageLoaded(e) {
            /// for each successful load we count down
            count--;
            //if (count === 0) 
            if (count === 0) 
            start(); //start when nothing more to count
        }
        function start() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
        context.drawSvg('/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg', 0, 0, 400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue);  

           for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {

               /// as we know the alpha ball has index 1 we use that here for images
               context.drawImage(images[1], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
           }
            for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {             
               context.drawImage(images[2], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
           }
        }

        function draw1(scaleValue){             
            context.save();     
            context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)   
            context.globalAlpha = 0.5;                      
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   
            context.restore();          
            context.save(); 
            context.drawSvg('/static/images/awesome_tiger.svg', 0, 0, 400*scaleValue, 400*scaleValue)
            context.scale(scaleValue, scaleValue);
            for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON[i]; i++) {
                   /// as we know the alpha ball has index 1 we use that here for images
                   context.drawImage(images[1], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
               }    
            for(var i = 0, pos; pos = dataJSON2[i]; i++) {
                   /// as we know the alpha ball has index 1 we use that here for images
                   context.drawImage(images[2], pos.x, pos.y, 20/scaleValue, 20/scaleValue);
               }
            context.restore();
        }; 
        draw1(scaleValue);


    }
```

Comment: What you've shown us above will not cause that error.  Are you sure about the array?

Comment: @Archer : I edited my question with the original code.

Comment: You're running `imageLoaded` before pushing the image into the array.

Comment: Use the files array instead of the images array.

Comment: @Archer : Tried but no result. May be I am doing something wrong. Above question source is updated again. Kindly take a look once again. Thank you

Comment: @Archer : Problem is coming in draw1(scaleValue) function.

Comment: How to set decrements count to zero?

Comment: For drawing images with drawImage used images array and for drawSvg used files array. For one SVG file it is working fine now. But need to optimize. Thank you for hints.